# Sorting an int array using a bubble sort, while keeping a String array at the same indices not working

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I've run into a little problem that I can't seem to fix, and I'm a little crushed for time. Basically, I'm using this simple bubble sort to print a numerically sorted transcript of a students grades, and I need to keep the String array of course codes together with the marks.

```
    // Using bottom to check the smaller list each time
            int bottom = marks.length - 1;

            // Once there are no more swaps, the list is sorted and it will leave
            boolean hadSwap = true;
            while (hadSwap) {
                // If there are no more swaps, it will leave
                hadSwap = false;
                
                // Checking ALL elements that could need to be moves
                for (int i = 0; i < bottom; i++) {
                
                    // Checking two elements next to eachother to see if they need to be swapped
                    if (marks[i] > marks[i + 1]) {
                        hadSwap = true;
                        // If they need to be swapped, swap them
                        int temp = marks[i];
                        marks[i] = marks[i + 1];
                        courses[i] = courses[i+1];
                        marks[i + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
                // The final item is in the right spot, shorten the list
                bottom--;
            }
    
}
```

The algorithm works, but the output for the transcript with the courses[i] swapping the same way that the marks[i] do, is this:

```
Course  Mark
---------------
HZT4U   12
HZT4U   43
CLN4U   45
CLN4U   63
CLN4U   81
CLN4U   89
CLN4U   89
CLN4U   92
```

I'm not sure why it overwrites the other course codes, and after 2 it goes to a different code, but I'm sure it's something little that I'm overlooking. I'm still new to this, so hopefully someone can help, thanks so much!

Comment: You will need to actually _swap_ the `courses` as you do with the `marks`. Currently, this `courses[i] = courses[i+1];` doesn't _swap_ but overwrite the courses at index `i` with the one of `i+1`.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you!!